# Can you help me solve this DB logic?

Tags: database

So this is more like a logical problem that I'm stuck.

There are three tables: Salesman, Buyer and Product.

What I want to know is what product a buyer bought, how many and the time (hours) he did did that. For that I was thinking in generating another table containing a FK to the product Table, a FK to the buyer table, the time and the amount.

The main problem here for me is that I can't manage to see where the salesman fits. I'd like to hear the logic you guys will come with.

This is probably a very dumb question but I'll be glad if someone helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need  at least  two more tables. First one, `PURCHASE` to store general information about the sale , and `PURCHASE_PRODUCT` .
Something like that should give you a good start.

`PURCHASE(purchase_id, purchase_datetime,  salesman_id, buyer_id, hours_spent )` 
Primary Key - purchase_id, Foreign key - salesman_id refers Salesman table PK, Foreign key - buyer_id refers Buyer table PK

`PURCHASE_PRODUCT(purchase_id, product_id, amount )`
Primary key - composite on purchase_id and product_id , Foreign Key - purchase_id refers `PURCHASE.purchase_id` , Foreign key - product_id refers Product table PK

There are many things that may be changed depends on the requirements. You may want to store 2 dates in `PURCHASE` table , e.g. `purchase_begin`, `purchase_end` instead of `purchase_datetime`, `hours_spent` to keep track of time; some other attributes (like discount) may be added as well. `PURCHASE_PRODUCT` can contain product price at time of purchase, maybe another discount, etc.
Instead of composite Primary Key on columns  `PURCHASE_PRODUCT(purchase_id, product_id)` you may decide to add a surrogate primary key , i.e.
`PURCHASE_PRODUCT(PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID(PK), purchase_id, product_id, amount )`,

Answer (score 0):

Create a table named "SALES". Have it to contain the foreign key of product id, salesman and buyer. Have a primary key of salesID.

Comment: And also the amount and the time I suppose?